# Domain mapping with virtual hosts how to prevent seeing folder tree?

Tags: apache

What I mean by this is, when domain mapping, pointing multiple domains to one ip-address, there is a primary folder, `/var/www/html` here the index file placed here would be what comes up when searching the server directly by ip-address or by `primarysite.com` which is equivalent to `/var/www/html/index.php`.

When I search  `secondarysite.com`, this is more than likely represented by `/var/www/html/secondarysite` which does not show in the url bar, what would show is `secondsarysite.com` as searched. But you could find that folder by typing `primarysite.com/secondarysite` so I don't want to see that.

That's done by URL rewrite correct?

Can that be permanent so as to not show the folder structure / multiple domains on the same ip unless requested directly by domain name?

Answer (score 0):

It's cleaner to have one directory per site. (so you can have, for example, clean site-wide backups)

You should move your primary domain vhost to /var/www/html/primarysite.com resolve this problem ?

If you really want to leave your primary site as /var/www/html, you must edit your "primary vhost", /etc/apache2/sites-available/primarysite.conf (or so), and add :

```
<Directory /secondarysite/>
    deny from all
</Directory>
```

(maybe you'll have to put in the absolute path to the folder)

I really don't recommend this method, because you'll have to remember this every time you add a site on the server. Moving each site to its own folder solves this once and for good.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you are trying to make 2 vHosts, inaccessible in the folder structure from each other? Rewrites / .htaccess may to be the best method to accomplish this goal. A cleaner / safer way is you can make two folders not inside each other (such as */var/www/primarysite/public_html* and */var/www/secondarysite/public_html*) and use the apache config to set them both up for those directories.

Try adding this to your apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/primarysite/public_html
ServerName primarysite.com
# Other configs
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/secondarysite/public_html
ServerName secondarysite.com
# Other configs
</VirtualHost>
```

More info [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) and [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html). Hope this helped!